# How to close the DatagramSocket and reuse it

Tags: android, sockets

I have this code on which I am receiving data through the android phone

```
 public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true) {
                        final String hey;
                        int server_port = 9875;
                        byte[] message = new byte[255];
                        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
                        DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(server_port);
                        s.receive(p);
                        hey = new String( message, 0 , p.getLength());
                        Log.d("MESSAGE: ", "Message is:" + hey);
                        s.close();

                        //codes for setting the Ultrasonic Sensor
                        if (hey.equals("Strainer is Empty")){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Empty.setAlpha((float) 0.8);
                                    Full.setAlpha((float) 0.2);
                                    SFull.setAlpha((float) 0.2);
                                    AFull.setAlpha((float) 0.2);

                                }
                            });
                        }

                        if(hey.equals("Strainer is Full")){
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Full.setAlpha((float) 0.8);
                                    Empty.setAlpha((float)0.2);
                                    SFull.setAlpha((float) 0.2);
                                    AFull.setAlpha((float) 0.2);
                                }
                            });
                        }
```

The problem is whenever i go back to my main activity and call this one, error seems to point out on the Datagram Socket. I have read about binding the address but i do not know on how to implement it

Comment: Why? Just create the socket ahead of the loop.

Comment: even if i do that error still persists. java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

Comment: Only if someone else is using the port. More likely youmjust re-ran the old code.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the issue when i try to implement it this way

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(null);
                        s.setReuseAddress(true);
                        s.setBroadcast(true);
                        s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(server_port));
```